# Does satisfy $f(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^2}$ the hypothesis of Halasz’s inequality?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ the **sum of divisor function**. I would like to know if I can write an example of some of the following **Theorem 1** or **Theorem 2** from $$f(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^2}$$ in **Tao**, [A cheap version of Halasz’s inequality](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/11/23/a-cheap-version-of-halaszs-inequality/#more-8594).

> **Question.** It is, does satisfy  the arithmetic function $f(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^2}$ the hipothesis of **Halasz’s inequality**? **Thanks in advance.**

I know that (for integers $n\geq 1$) it is easy to deduce that $f(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^2}$ is a **multiplicative function bounded in magnitude** by $1$. And $f(p)=\frac{p+1}{p^2}$ for prime numbers.

Secondly I can write (1) of Theorem 1 in the cited theorems as $$\sum_{p\leq x} \left(  \frac{1}{p}-\frac{(p+1)\cos(t\log p)}{p^3} \right)\geq M,$$
but precisely it is what I need to prove or disprove.

The additional information that I 've is a **Mertens theorem** tell us the known asymptotic $\sum_{p\leq x} \frac{1}{p}=\log\log x+A+O((\log x)^{-1})$ . And the **expansion series for the cosine function**.

My previous **Question** is: can you prove or disprove that there is a constant $M>0$ such that satisfies the hypothesis of **Halasz’s inequality**
$$\sum_{p\leq x} \left(  \frac{1}{p}-\frac{(p+1)\cos(t\log p)}{p^3} \right)\geq M?$$

I would like to know this example to understand better the dependence of $x$ on $T$ (see **Theorem 2**) and such $M$. If after you answer my question you want state the deduction of such theorem you are welcome.

Comment: You realize that $\sum_p \left| (p+1) \cos(t\log p) / p^3 \right| $ is absolutely convergent right?  It clearly doesn't have a strong effect on the sum, regardless of $T$.  Also this choice of $f(n)$ clearly converges to $0$, so questions about the mean value of $f(n)$ are fairly moot.

Comment: @ErickWong if there is an implicit question about $\sum_p \left| (p+1) \cos(t\log p) / p^3 \right|$ I don't see it. Currently my mathematical reasoning is not the best. Thus my intention was try use the cited inequality with this example of $f$ from the viewpoint more naive. If you with your answer can improve the quality of myself question then this post is a best reference of all users to know how study if such question has mathematical meaning and what you can state about an hypothetical answer. I don't know very well the relationship between your claims and which I've written. Many thanks.

Comment: Very thanks much to **Erick Wong** for his answer, it is incredible and add all details, that students can understand. **I hope that his merit of placing here a great reference with his answer will be rewarded.**

Comment: You are very kind, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question looks sincere but it has a very elementary answer, so I will try to be very clear, because you might be harboring some misconceptions:

First of all, *every* multiplicative function bounded by $1$ satisfies the conditions of Halasz's inequality.  The inequality applies to any fixed $x$ and $M$; the only parameter that is universally quantified is $t$.  For any fixed $x$, so long as $f$ isn't identically $1$ on the primes up to $x$, then the summation in the condition will always be bounded away from $0$, so there will always be some $M>0$ that works (for that fixed $x$), thus giving an upper bound on the mean value of $f$ (i.e. $\frac1x\sum_{n\le x} f(n)$).

Typically, the whole point of the Halasz inequality is to be able to conclude that $M \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, so we get a (quantitative) bound on the mean value of $f$ that converges to $0$.  From that perspective, I don't follow the motivation for your main question, which asks for a constant $M>0$: constant in what?

In any case, it is very clear that $f(p) < 2/p$, and that's all it takes to conclude that $M \to \infty$ (in fact we can easily loosen this to $f(p) \ll p^{-\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$), because:

$$\left|\frac{f(p) \cos(t \log p)}{p}\right| < \frac2{p^2},$$

so $\sum_{p=2}^\infty f(p) \cos(t\log p)/p$ is an absolutely convergent series, which implies that $\sum_{p\le x} f(p) \cos(t\log p)/p$ is bounded by a universal constant $C$.

The triangle inequality then gives
$$ \sum_{p\leq x} \left(  \frac{1}{p}-\frac{(p+1)\cos(t\log p)}{p^3} \right) > \sum_{p\le x} \frac{1}{p} - C = \log \log x + A - C + O(\log^{-1} x) > \log \log x + B,$$

for some constant $B$ independent of $T$.  The point here is that $f(p)$ is so tiny that the $1/p$ term is by far the dominant part of the sum and there is no question that $M\to\infty$ so that the mean value of $f$ is zero.  The qualitative essence of Halasz's theorem is that the only way that $f(n)$ can avoid having a mean value is if it approximates some function of the form $n^{-it}$, and $\sigma(n)/n^2$ does a very poor job of approximating this (on account of being too small).

But on top of that it's easy to show that $f(n) = O(n^{-1/2})$ so that $f(n) \to 0$.  We don't really need Halasz's inequality to see that $f$ has mean value $0$.

Comment: Very thanks much for your claim that each multiplicative function bounded by 1 satisifies Halasz's inequality, Now I understand better what is the use of such inequality. My question seem a monographic of all mistakes that one can write using the inequality, your answer the best explanation that now is a reference in this site. **I hope that this your answer has the best score**, and see the best questions from other users about this inequality. Also I want to say that it is appreciated details as your proof for absolutely convergent series, or your claim about constants, and other detials...